# Integral $\int \frac{1}{x(1-x)^n}dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, binomial-theorem

I am try to integrate the following function:$$\frac{1}{x(1-x)^n}$$ I have searched on some online integral calculator, but they are not solving it. 
Can we use binomial theorem in this?

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions?

Comment: The antiderivative can always be given (for integer $n$) in terms of logs and rational functions via partial fraction decomposition. If you are dead-set on using the Binomial Theorem, note $\frac{1}{x}(1-x)^{-n} = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty {n+k-1 \choose k}x^k$ so that $\int\frac{1}{x}(1-x)^{-n} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {n+k-1 \choose k}\int x^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty {n+k-1 \choose k}k^{-1}x^k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include non-integer $n$, Maple uses a hypergeometric
$$
\int \frac{dx}{x(1-x)^n} = nx\;\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}\big(1,1,1+n;\,2,2;\,x\big)+\ln  \left( x \right) + C
$$

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the Binomial theorem, but if you make substitution $y=1-x$, it becomes $-\int \frac{1}{(1-y)y^n}$. Now notice that 
$$
\frac{1}{(1-y)y^n} = \frac{1}{y^n}+\frac{1}{y^{n-1}}+\dots+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{1-y}
$$
(you might want to think why this is). So you have finitely many terms you should be able to integrate.